# Laravel 5.2 proper foreach syntax

Tags: laravel-5

what is the difference between the following syntax ?

```
foreach($products as $product) {
// loop body
}
```

and

```
foreach($product as $product) {
 //loop body
}
```

got error some time when second one is used.
Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer after your update

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is wrong

```
 foreach($product as $product) {
 //loop body
 }
```

As we loop through the `$products` and get out every single `$product` of it 
so we pass the array first then we follow it by the name of the single variable we want to use later  your `foreach loop` should be like this:

```
foreach($products as $product){
 //loop body 
}
```